# encrypted token using AES does not change

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I need to generate different token for every run of AES (in JAVA) for that what I did is I appended the string to be encrypted with the current system time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` in java and seperated both of them using a pipe character "|". But the issue am facing is that the encrypted string is same for every run and while decrypting I get the correct string.. Why is it happening so?

Code for encryption :

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AESEncryptor {
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private final static byte[] keyValue =new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't','S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
            byte[] encryptedValue = Base64.encodeBase64(encVal);
            String encryptedPass = new String (encryptedValue);
            return encryptedPass;
        }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decordedValue =  Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }

}


1st run :
argument passed to encrypt : somepassword|1364311519852
encrypted string : 5pQ1kIC+8d81AD7zbLOZA==(encrypted string)
decrypted string : somepassword|1364311519852

2nd run : 
argument passed to encrypt : somepassword|1364311695048
encrypted string : 5pQ1kIC+8d81AD7zbLOZA==(same encrypted string as before)
decrypted string : somepassword|1364311695048
```

Can someone help why is it happening so?

Comment: Your ciphertext is way to short for it to be encrypted from "somestring|1364300620387" nor could it decrypt back to it. If we assume your mode doesn't use padding even the Base64 should be atleast 1.25 times longer that the raw bytes. Not possible.

Comment: The cipher text I mentioned above was a dummy one, the actual one is 24 characters long. I gave the dummy one just to give an example of the situation I am facing.

Comment: Yeah when you purposefully give wrong information no one can help you.

Comment: come on @jbtule! i was trying an encrypt a password using it, that is why thought of not giving the exact string. now have edited the question with the exact values. You can check them now..

Comment: There's still no way that can be the full encrypted string. I'd advise you to post a [short, self-consistent compilable example](http://sscce.org) that we can compile and run to reproduce the results you describe. One of the advantages of doing so is that there's a fair chance that, while writing and testing the example code, you'll find the cause of the problem yourself. And if not, it will make it _much_ easier for others to help you.

Comment: Yeah, my first comment is still in effect, your base64 value is shorter than your plaintext. Not possible.

Comment: guys this is the actual output I am getting.. I am giving the exact java file so that you can test and see.

Comment: I tried it - this is what I am getting `Mm6tfoUN1JxaOogGtXBb2vZFZo9eALEgbFEg9UItkGA=`
and `Mm6tfoUN1JxaOogGtXBb2rRRH++mi8KJqi+XBtbqapA=` As expected first part is same but second part different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't believe you could decrypt your output (I do believe the output provided by @user93353).  ECB mode is not ideal, you should probably switch to CBC.

```
private static final String ALGO = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
```

Add a randomly generated IV, prepend it to your ciphertext,  and your ciphertext will entirely look like random data, even if you encrypt the same text over and over again.

Since you mentioned the word token, which suggests you are using the ciphertext for authenticity, which is not something the aes provides on it's own. I think you should strongly look into [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), specifically encrypt(aes-cbc)-then-mac(hmac), where you would postpend a mac of your ciphertext and iv to the end of your ciphertext.